# Opening InfoWindow automatically when adding marker Google Maps v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker, infowindow

Is there a way to open the infowindow automatically when we add a marker?
Using this code to add the marker but infowindow only opens when clicking the marker:

```
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("Title")
            .snippet("Snippet")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

According to the documents of [Google Maps for Android V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker):

> An info window allows you to display information to the user when they
>   tap on a marker on a map. By default, an info window is displayed when
>   a user taps on a marker if the marker has a title set. Only one info
>   window is displayed at a time. If a user clicks on another marker, the
>   current window will be hidden and the new info window will be
>   displayed. You can show an info window programmatically by calling
>   ***showInfoWindow()*** on the target marker. An info window can be hidden by
>   calling ***hideInfoWindow()***.

You can show the info window like this:

```
Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                     .position(latLng)
                     .title("Title")
                     .snippet("Snippet")
                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                     .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: In ifo window i am adding snippet and and title but by default snippet not visible it will be draw out of window. Even when click the marker wnippet goes out of view only title will be visible. User has to pan map to see it. Is ther anywat to fix it?