# How to display multiple info windows in different locations from firestore

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to the android studio.I already know that there are multiple questions  related with my issue in javascript. But what I want is to display multiple info windows for the locations, retreived from firestore.I have already displayed multiple locations from firestore.But when I click any marker on the google map, the info window is always displayed only for the last location detail in the firestore.
This is my code for InfoWindowAdapter:

```
public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_marker_info_window, null);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
        TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);
        TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);
        tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);
        tvLng.setText("Longitude:"+ latLng.longitude);

        return v;
    }
}
```

This is my code for MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements OnMapReadyCallback  {
    static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 23;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Button btn;
    private DatabaseReference collectionRef;
    private GeoFirestore geoFirestore;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;

   Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkPermission();

        CollectionReference collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("my-collection");
        GeoFirestore geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(collectionRef);
        ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
     //   collectionRef.push().setValue(marker);

    }


    private void checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        } else {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;




        FirebaseFirestore mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference mOrderRef = mDatabase.collection("my-collection");
      

        Task<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshotTask = mOrderRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.contains("latitude") && documentSnapshot.contains("longitude")) {
                        String lat = (String) documentSnapshot.get("latitude");
                        String lon = (String) documentSnapshot.get("longitude");
                        String Place = (String) documentSnapshot.get("place");
                        String Reason = (String) documentSnapshot.get("reason");

                        if (lat != null && lon != null && !lat.isEmpty() && !lon.isEmpty()) {
                            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat.trim());
                            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(lon.trim());
                            final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(Place));
                                  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                            MarkerInfoWindowAdapter markerInfoWindowAdapter = new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(markerInfoWindowAdapter);
                            googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                  //  mMap.clear();
                                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                 //   MarkerOptions markerOptions1= new MarkerOptions();
                                    markerOptions.position(latLng);

                                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                                    Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                 //   Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions1);

                                    marker1.showInfoWindow();
                               



                                    return true;
                                }



                            });

                     //  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(Place));
                     //  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));


                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        });



       }

}
```

Can someone help me to fix my issue?

Comment: Have you checked out this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40106995/8779275

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a Community Wiki since it's based on a Community Answer and the comment of @M_droid.

It does not really matter where the map data is coming from since the issue is that you are using the default markers, as you can see in this [Community Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40106995/8779275):

> The default markers can **only show one info window at a time**. However, you can easily show more, using the [Maps Android library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility).