# Google Maps Android API - How to auto select marker?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm adding a marker to my `SupportMapFragment` as shown. I would like for the title to be shown automatically, instead of requiring the user to tap on the marker. Is there a way?

```
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(
                    Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("lat")),
                    Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("lng"))
            ))
            .title(getArguments().getString("name")));

    try {
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(
                        Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("lat")),
                        Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("lng")))
                , new Float(15.0)
        ));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //ignore
    }
```

Comment: check this link it's very help full to you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899619/opening-infowindow-automatically-when-adding-marker-google-maps-v2-android

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @JigneshJain,

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(
                    Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("lat")),
                    Double.parseDouble(getArguments().getString("lng"))
            ))
            .title(getArguments().getString("name")));
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: welcome @Terence one suggestion for you first google it than come here for help.

Comment: @JigneshJain of course I did, I just wasn't using the correct keywords.