# How to show title of the marker without clicking on that?

Tags: android

I want to show marker name without clicking on the marker.

How can i do that one?

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(name1).title("bangalore"));
```

Comment: Already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899619/opening-infowindow-automatically-when-adding-marker-google-maps-v2-android

Comment: marker.showInfoWindow() is the method you are looking for

Comment: i just want to display title not infowindow or something

Answer (score 3):

you can use showInfoWindow() after creating marker. [official document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows)

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .title("Melbourne"));
melbourne.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: This works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LatLng)
                .title(title).snippet(snippet).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(icon)));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this library

http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

This open-source library contains classes that are useful for a wide range of applications using the Google Maps Android API.